# Magento 2 Module Upgrade Error

Tags: magento2, php, module, database, extensions

I added a new module in the `app/code` directory and activated the module in `app/etc/config.php`, but when I try to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh yes it's running on a VM.  I'll need to ssh into it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Magento installed in VM but you try to run commands on host system